# Render instantiated prefab in a frame

Tags: unity-game-engine, render

Say, I have a Prefab A and B.

Now A is On Screen, and B is not even instantiated.

I want to switch from A to B. Specifically,

1) Deactivate A

2) Instantiate B, and then set B active

The problem is that nothing is shown in that frame.
A is disabled, but B is not rendered even though it is instantiated.

I have no choice but to disable A in a frame after by using coroutine, but I want to know why it happens.

Comment: This makes no sense. What you're saying is happening is impossible in the way you are describing what you're doing. Please post you code.

Comment: What do you need it for and how exactly do you check if the object is rendered in that frame?